# Синхронизация сайта на Drupal и приложения на Android и использование GUID в качестве идентификатора таблиц на Drupal-сайте

Tags: android, drupal, синхронизация

Добрый день.

Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли каким-то образом использовать в качестве идентификатора в таблицах Drupal не числовые id, а глобальный [GUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) ?

Просто намечается один проект, где планируется как сайт на Drupal 7, так и приложение на Android (а возможно, и не только на Android). И там везде будет возможность вносить информацию. И вот для облегчения синхронизации данных возникла мысль использовать GUID.

Или, если есть другие способы синхронизации в данном случае, без использования  GUID ?

Answer (score 2):

Чисто навскидку, модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid смотрели? Как раз и для 7 есть.